# Is a non-blocking connect guaranteed to fail with EINPROGRESS?

Tags: sockets

If I set up a socket for non-blocking operation, as follows:

```
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);
int rc = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

...is `connect` *guaranteed* to fail with `EINPROGRESS`, or do I need to handle the case where it succeeds immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Connecting to `127.0.0.1` may connect or fail immediately.

Comment: "Connecting to 127.0.0.1 connects or fails immediately." -- not in my testing, it doesn't, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the case where it succeeds immediately. That's why it returns 0 or -1. The documentation doesn't make any exception about that for non-blocking mode.